# how to filter data frame and select coordinates using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame similar like this :

```
df <- data.frame(V1=c(0, 100, 0, 0), V2=c(100, 0, 0 , 0), V3=c(50, 50, 0, 0 ), V4=c( 0,0,0,100))
rownames(df) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
```

and I would like to extract some information using `dplyr` in R.

1. First of all I would like to extract all the coordinates (rows and cols) that are different from 100 or 0 (V3; A =50 and B= 50)
2. I would like to generate some percent about this data ( A= 50% and B =50%)

any help would be great!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not fully understand what you want to achieve but does this help you?

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(V1=c(0, 100, 0, 0), V2=c(100, 0, 0 , 0), V3=c(50, 50, 0, 0 ), V4=c( 0,0,0,100))
rownames(df) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
df %>% 
  rownames_to_column()%>% 
  pivot_longer(!rowname, names_to="values") %>% 
  filter(value %in% 1:99)
```

Comment: Nice solution. I would just change the last row to filter(!(Num %in% c(0, 100) ) to make it general.

Answer (score 1):

In base R you can try

```
gr <- which((df != 0 & df != 100), arr.ind = T)
cbind.data.frame(name = rownames(df)[gr[,1]], value=df[gr], percent = paste0(df[gr], "%"))
  name value percent
1    A    50     50%
2    B    50     50%
```